# SQL Server Management Studio shows not all dependencies

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Right click on a table -> View Dependencies:

Does not correctly show all tables which are linked via foreign keys. One table is simply missing.

Any ideas why this could be the case?

The foreign keys are definitively setup correctly and are working correctly.

The clicked table is a "master" table, and all linked tables are in the same schema.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.5538.0

Comment: Do you see the same view if you select the table and click delete? Of course, don't delete it, however, there is a comprehensive dependency view in the prompt dialog..

Comment: @lrb I know what you mean. I tried it, but there comes the same dependency dialog like when you directly click on "View dependencies" in the first place. And same result! It is really strange, I can see no error in my foreign key definitons. It's about two totally plain normal tables linked together via foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, standard dependency viewer works wrong in some cases (e.g. if you are using CTE).
You can try another dependency viewer (e.g. [this](https://sqlrefactorstudio.com/Features/Details/ViewDependencies) )

Comment: OK, but I don't use any CTEs - these are two totally normal plain tables linked together via foreign key references. Very basic IMHO. Thanks for the link, I will have a look at this tool.